# CallingBotSample does not throw welcome Text with Adaptive Card

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to run this sample, and not having much luck :

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp/

I created an App on Azure and then used https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new to create a BOT and link it to this App and enabled Calling and configured an ngrok URL so that I can run the project locally under Visual Studio.

I have configured the App and the sample as explained in the readme and sideloaded it into teams, installing it to the General channel of a nominated Team.

Although I can make a call to the BOT, and it answers with the wav file in the Visual Studio project (which runs locally via ngrok), I am not seeing the adaptive card in Teams with which to do call control, as shown in the instructions/readme at

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp/README.md

Edit:
I note that CallingBot.OnMembersAddedAsync() which looks like it might be responsible for showing the card, does fire when I add a new member to the team, but then throws the error:
*System.Exception.Message.get returned "Failed to acquire token for client credentials. (AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '<>' was not found in the directory 'Bot Framework'.*

Any suggestions please - what am I missing

EDIT 26 Nov 21:
configuration as follows

```
in the supplied manifest, we set 
=================================
the id to the           "Teams App ID"
we set the Bot id to the    "Azure Application (client) ID"


in the appsettings.json, we set
================================
  "MicrosoftAppId":         "Azure Application (client) ID"
  "MicrosoftAppPassword":   "Azure Application password"


  "AzureAd": {
    "TenantId":     "Company Tenant ID"
    "ClientId":     "Azure Application (client) ID"
    "ClientSecret":     "Azure Application password"

  "Bot": {
    "AppId":        "Azure Application (client) ID"
    "AppSecret":    "Azure Application password"


  "UserId": "User A id within Teams",

  "Users": [
    {
      "DisplayName":    "Name of User B",
      "Id":         "ID of User B"
    },
    {
      "DisplayName":    "Name of User C",
     "Id":      "ID of User C"
    },
    {
      "DisplayName":    "Name of User D",
     "Id":      "ID of User D"
    },
    {
      "DisplayName":    "Name of User E",
     "Id":      "ID of User E"
    }
  ]


When I add the manifest to a team with the code already running, OnMembersAddedAsync() fires and that leads to AdapterWithErrorHandler() firing with the exception :

"Failed to acquire token for client credentials. 
(AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '"Azure Application (client) ID"' was not found in the directory 'Bot Framework'. 
This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. 
You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\n
Trace ID: 2eea2365-0e69-434d-befa-eeeb874a5101\r\n
Correlation ID: 0b06ce58-c03f-4a9b-a897-890f910269b7\r\nTimestamp: 2021-11-26 14:08:27Z)"
```

Comment: Could you please check the scope of your bot and install it accordingly and also debug your code to check if control is coming in the code section which is responsible to send the card.

Comment: scopes in the manifest is set to  "scopes": [ "personal", "team", "groupchat" ],.  When running in debug I note the following exception is trapped when I add a member to the team....  System.Exception.Message.get returned "Failed to acquire token for client credentials. 
  (AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '<<redacted AppID>>' was not found in the directory 'Bot Framework'. 
  This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. 
  You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Comment: With regards to the above error, note that I am sideloading the App/Bot into teams.

Comment: In the manifest I have the following fields set with the AppID referenced in the exception:  "id":, "bots"."botId".  In the appsettings I have the following fields set to the AppID : "MicrosoftAppId", "AzureAd"."ClientId", "Bot"."AppID"

Comment: I have checked that my tenant ID is correct, and that the AppID in question is indeed registered against that tenant ID.  Which at best makes the error message confusing.   Any suggestions please.

Comment: Still no resolution unfortunately

Comment: We ar able to get the Welcome text with Adaptive card, so it looks like the issue with the configuration. Could you please reverify it again and check it.

Comment: I have added some notes about how we have it configured under EDIT 26 Nov 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that although we had set the BOT to be multitenant, we had *not*, additionally set the App to be multitenant.
i.e., by doing :

- Click Authentication
- Make sure Supported Account Types is set to
  “Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)”.
- Click Save

Comment: Where is this?  In Azure?